# Gitlab package registry throw 404 on npm publish

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to publish a package to Gitlab package registry but it keeps erroring me with `404 @my-scope/<package-name> is not in this registry`.

Initially I followed the instructions in [here official docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#authenticate-to-the-package-registry)

This is how my `.npmrc` looks like:

```
@my-scope:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/npm/:_authToken=${TOKEN}
```

also I've added `publishConfig` to `package.json`

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "@my-scope:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/npm/"
  },
```

When I run `npm publish` I keep getting 404 error as below.

```
npm notice Publishing to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/npm/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/npm/@my-scope%2fpackage-name
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@my-scope/package-name@1.5.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.npmrc` should looks like this according to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#install-npm-packages-from-other-organizations):

```
@foo:registry=https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${MY_TOKEN}
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<your_project_id>/packages/npm/:_authToken=${MY_TOKEN}
```